# How do i replicate a huge mount of data for loadbalancing purpose?

Tags: load-balancing

i had a website with huge mount of data (781GB), and now im about to do loadbalancing with my website.
the problem is how do i replicate my website to the other node ? does NFS / GlusterFS works in this case?

Comment: 781GB is not ridiculously large.  The problem with NFS is that it makes your original data a single point of failure.  By copying it to the other nodes, you'd have a live backup.

Comment: thanks for replying, but are there any method to easily copying this datas to another node, since the other node was cloud hosting, kind a struggled with this.

Comment: It's a tough situation.  You wouldn't want to use NFS over long distances, both for speed and because the bandwidth charges would kill you.  Is this in a database, or just a set of files?

Comment: Its a set of files.